# Instantiate a variable of type Interface

Tags: typescript

I want to dynamically instantiate a class in Typescript

Here's a code sample

```
interface IHtmlField {
  name: string
}

class TextInput implements IHtmlField {
  public name: string
}

class FileInput implements IHtmlField {
  public name: string
}

const fields: {[type: string]: IHtmlField} = {
  text: TextInput,
  file: FileInput
}

const type = 'text' // dynamic variable
const fieldCls = fields[type]
new fieldCls()
```

I'm getting this error
`Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.`

It's because the variable that I want to Instantiate is of type `IHtmlField`

Is there a workaround or a better way to do it?

Comment: `const cls: IHtmlField = TextInput` - this assignment works accidentally, just because functions (and classes) have `.name` attribute. Just for the sake of test change name to `n` and see it's broken already before the `new` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property type of `fields` should be not an `IHtmlField` instance, but a constructor function that constructs a subclass of `IHtmlField`:

```
const fields: {[type: string]: {new(): IHtmlField}} = {
  text: TextInput,
  file: FileInput
}
```

Comment: Amazing, worked like a charm! Can you link to some docs in which this is described? Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, like many advanced TypeScript concepts, this is poorly covered in the official documentation.  There's a little information [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes).  Your web search is as good as mine for finding additional resources.

Comment: I agree and here's some additional resources may someone find them useful https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7936#issuecomment-214900927

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works in this way:

```
interface IHtmlField {
    name: string
}

class TextInput implements IHtmlField {
    public name: string
}

class FileInput implements IHtmlField {
    public name: string
}

const fields: { [type: string]: IHtmlField } = {
    text: new TextInput(),
    file: new FileInput()
}

const type = 'text' // dynamic variable
const fieldCls = fields[type]

console.log(fieldCls.name);
//   new fieldCls()
```

Comment: You're missing the whole point of the original code: they need a factory.

Comment: I'll lookup how to create a factory the best way, thank you @zerkms